# Is it normal for a connection piece at outdoor HVAC unit to sweat heavily?

Tags: hvac

I noticed the connection piece at my outdoor HVAC unit has been sweating heavily when in use. It is in the 70s recently so not particularly hot out. I am worried about corrosion. Is this normal or should it be insulated like the section above it? Thanks in advance!

Here is an image of the excess moisture

[image: Sweaty pipes]

Comment: The insulation is looking rather tired and worn, I'd suggest it's time to replace it. Also, it appears that the sweat is primarily on the uninsulated portions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Condensation occurs more readily at lower temperatures, where the relative humidity is higher. You might not see as much if it was 90. It's not really a problem, as there's almost always some exposed metal anyway, and copper develops a patina that protects it (the brown).

FreeMan's right, though--fix the insulation on the pipe. You lose energy efficiency where the pipe is exposed, so you want at least *most* of it covered.